# I want to assign integer values to each combo box selection and to collectively print them in a text file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, user-controls

I am making a kind of student database, in which, for every new student, his/her details are added and then there is a combo box to choose the subject, and an adjacent edit control to enter the respective marks. I want to assign the marks simultaneously without pressing any button. How can this be achieved ??

The code-

```
void CFile03Dlg::OnSelchangeCombo()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here


        int n= m_SSubject.GetCurSel();
        arr[n]=m_SMarks;


}




void CFile03Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    int h=0;
    CStdioFile file_object(L"D:\\Docs\\Student.txt",CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeNoTruncate);


    CString fc1=m_SName, fc2=m_SClass, fc3=m_SRoll, fc4;
    file_object.SeekToEnd();

    for(h=0;h<3;h++)
    {
    fc4.Format(L"%d", arr[h]);
    }

     file_object.WriteString(L"Name: ");
     file_object.WriteString(fc1);
     file_object.WriteString(L"\n");

     file_object.WriteString(L"Class: ");
     file_object.WriteString(fc2);
     file_object.WriteString(L"\n");

     file_object.WriteString(L"Roll No.: ");
     file_object.WriteString(fc3);
     file_object.WriteString(L"\n");

    // file_object.WriteString(L"Name:");
      CString selection;

      for(h=0;h<3;h++)
      {


             if(h==0)
                {
                    m_SSubject.GetLBText(h, selection);
                    file_object.WriteString(selection);
                    file_object.WriteString(L"  Marks: ");
                    file_object.WriteString(fc4);

             }

             else if(h==1)
            {
                    m_SSubject.GetLBText(h, selection);
                file_object.WriteString(selection);

                file_object.WriteString(L"  Marks: ");
                    file_object.WriteString(fc4);
            }

             else if(h==2)
            {
                    m_SSubject.GetLBText(h, selection);
                file_object.WriteString(selection);

                file_object.WriteString(L"  Marks: ");
                    file_object.WriteString(fc4);
            }
             else if(h==3)
            {
                    m_SSubject.GetLBText(h, selection);
                file_object.WriteString(selection);

                file_object.WriteString(L"  Marks: ");
                    file_object.WriteString(fc4);
            }

            file_object.WriteString(L"\n");

      }  
    file_object.WriteString(L"\n");
    UpdateData(FALSE);

}
```

Comment: In every `if` `else-if` you are writing the same 4 line lines of code, then why need of these condition? you can write these 4 lines only once.

Comment: @Himanshu the respective values of `selection` are different

Comment: First for loop you are using is of no use, because loop is running from 0 to <3, so `fc4.Format(L"%d", arr[h]);` will save only last value. i.e `arr[2]`. you can remove this for loop.

Comment: @TarangGupta, no they are not, for h1 == 1,2 and 3 the code in the con dition is exactly the same.

Comment: @MichaelWalz here, `m_SSubject`is the variable of the combo box, now `GetLBText`gives us the data at the provided index(i.e `h`) and variable.. hence the values come out different for each case, anyways, i am going for a different approach now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every `if` `else-if` condition you are writing the same 4 line lines of code.

I think you need something like this:

```
for(h=0;h<3;h++)
{
    if(h==0)
    {

         m_SSubject.GetLBText(h, selection);
         file_object.WriteString(selection);
         file_object.WriteString(L"  Marks: ");
         fc4.Format(L"%d", arr[h]);  // here you will get marks.
         file_object.WriteString(fc4);// here you can pass fc4
    }
    else if()
    {
        // write condition similar...
    }

}
```

As you are running loop from 0 to <3, loop will run for 0,1 and 2. so why you have written condition

```
 else if(h==3) ???
```

How many values are there in combobox? if its 4 then run you for loop from `0` to `<=3`

Comment: @TarangGupta, okay fine :)